# zabbix with postgresql on AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-rds, zabbix

I have one EC2 instance and when I check connection with psql tool by it is OK.
psql --host= etc...

Basically, AWS RDS does not provide internal IP for connection. I have to use long URL Endpoint instead.

How to provide this endpoint address to zabbix web interface installation tool?
When I use endpoint in "Database host" it fails :(

Comment: How does it fail (please provide more details)? Did you install PHP postresql support? What about security groups? You may have also problem with selinux rules (centos/rhel/...). Generally: DNS record (for example mypostgresql.c6c8mwvfdgv0.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com) is not a problem and you can use it in your Zabbix.

Comment: install wizard shows "Cannot connect to the database". When Im trying to start zabbix server it fails an error "Zabbix server cannot work with a Zabbix proxy database".

Comment: Please check your security groups and selinux logs as I've mentioned before.

Comment: I use Ubuntu. I think zabbix server in the same conditions as psql tool. The latter works fine. So, security group is OK. I changed DBHost to a wrong endpoint and when I start the server it throws: "[Z3001] connection to database 'zabbix' failed: [0] could not translate host name "zzabbix-pg.blah.blah.rds.amazonaws.com" to address: Name or service not known". So, the problem with created database. Connection from zabbix works fine.

Comment: problem was with incompatibility db schema version and zabbix server from public repo.